# Strange log in Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, logging

It starts a few days ago and I can't remember directly after what. When I'm trying to test my project on a device my log starts with this(when i run project on a iOS Simulator it is not appear):

```
13:44:01.760 INFO  | cap lib: logger inited [iPhoneSenderHookLib.mm:512]
13:44:01.761 INFO  | my uid: 501 [iPhoneSenderHookLib.mm:513]
13:44:01.787 INFO  | chown ret:-1 [iPhoneSenderHookLib.mm:515]
13:44:01.805 INFO  | chmod ret:-1 [iPhoneSenderHookLib.mm:517]
13:44:01.806 NOTICE| identifier=1e546890 [iPhoneSenderHookLib.mm:539]
13:44:01.806 NOTICE| my bundle id is 111 [iPhoneSenderHookLib.mm:541]
```

also every new project now shows me this log when i try to run it.
And looks like it freezes my app at start from 2 to 4 seconds but I'm not sure because I making some highly loaded app prototype now. Looks like some C++ library linking to my project or script, but I haven't C++ files in it, it's pure obj-c projects. Projects started by me from scratch, any 3rd party library wasn't linked and I haven't any scripts listed in Xcode. What can it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer was simple. Someone made jailbreak on this device. After updating iOS (and deleting jailbreak appropriately) strange log gone away

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's coming from iPhoneSenderHookLib.mm on line 512.  Have you added this file to your project or projects?

Comment: I haven't C++ files in it, it's pure obj-c projects. Projects started by me from scratch, any 3rd party library wasn't linked and I haven't any scripts listed in Xcode or .mm files in project.